# imagecreatefromjpeg and similar functions are not working in PHP

Tags: php, gd

I’ve searched for this and the solutions provided in past questions are completely incomprehensible to me. Whenever I run functions like `imagecreatefromjpeg`, I get this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() ...

I’m working on a new install of PHP; my last installation never had this problem. I don’t get what’s going on.

Comment: is GD enabled/installed?

Comment: Make sure you have `GD2` not only installed but also activated in your `php.ini`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: check this answer, you will learn how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/a/72506454/8133129

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Install GD Library

Which OS you are using?

http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Windows
http://www.dmxzone.com/go/5001/how-do-i-install-gd-in-windows/

Linux
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-or-add-php-gd-support-to-apache/

Comment: Gah, the solution in that link worked fine. I've been fiddling with this forever and couldn't get it to work, didn't know it was that simple. Thank you for finding this!

Answer (score 78):

In Ubuntu/Mint (Debian based)

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

Comment: and /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: @ChrisV Only if you're using Apache.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14, imageantialias is missing: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/74647

Comment: for newer version, use php-gd or php7.0-gd

Comment: If you're using php-fpm it is sufficient to restart only php-fpm. One of many advantages of using that, as php-fpm usually restarts much faster than a web server.

Answer (score 37):

If you are like me and you are using one of the [PHP Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) as your base, you need to add the gd extension using different instructions then what's discussed above.

For the `php:7.4.1-apache` image you need to add in your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd
```

These dev packages are needed for compilation of the GD php extension. For me this resulted in activation of GD with PNG and JPEG support in PHP.

Comment: Thanks Paul, it worked like a charm for me! \o/ :rocket:

Comment: Yes, this is the solution

Answer (score 24):

You can still get `Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()` even if GD is installed.

The solution is to install/enable jped lib:

On **Ubuntu**:

```
    apt-get install libjpeg-dev
    apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

On  **CentOS**:

```
    yum install libjpeg-devel
    yum install freetype-devel
```

If compiling from source add `--with-jpeg-dir --with-freetype-dir` or `--with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-freetype-dir=/usr`.

For more details check https://www.tectut.com/2015/10/solved-call-to-undefined-function-imagecreatefromjpeg/

Comment: I tried to compile 7.2 and 7.4 and 7.2 lacks `imagecreatefromjpeg` while 7.4 doesn't...

Answer (score 21):

You must enable the library GD2.

Find your (proper) php.ini file

Find the line: ;extension=php_gd2.dll and remove the semicolon in the front.

The line should look like this:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Then restart apache and you should be good to go.

Comment: Just a note for anyone looking at this since php.ini is a big file. This line is under the `Dynamic Extensions` category (roughly middle of the document)

Comment: Just a note for anyone using PHP 8 or greater it will be `extension=gd` instead.

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo apt-get install phpx.x-gd 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

x.x is the versión php.

Answer (score 12):

For php 7 on Ubuntu:

> sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd

Answer (score 9):

After installing `php5-gd` **apache restart is needed**.

Answer (score 8):

I spent so much time trying to figure this out on Windows after installing `PHP Version 8.0.11`.

I created this `phpinfo.php` file to check whether GD was loaded:

```
<?php
if (extension_loaded('gd')) {
  print 'gd loaded';
} else {
  print 'gd NOT loaded';
}

phpinfo(); ?>
```

If it returns `gd NOT loaded` then ensure that in your `php.ini` file you have the following unchecked:

```
; - Many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) or ext/ (PHP 5+)
;   extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5+).
;   Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
extension=gd
```

Further down they'll be a section for `extension_dir` on Windows you need to uncheck the following:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"
```

You should now see `gd loaded` when running the `phpinfo.php` file and any function calls (like `imagecreatefromjpeg()`) should now work as intended.

Comment: thanks man, time saver 

Answer (score 7):

In CentOS, RedHat, etc. use below command. don't forget to restart the Apache. Because the PHP module has to be loaded.

```
yum -y install php-gd
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before, you might need GD library installed.

On a shell, check your php version first:
`php -v`

Then install accordingly. In my system (Linux-Ubuntu) it's php version 7.0:
`sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd`

Restart your webserver:
`systemctl restart apache2`

You should now have GD library installed and enabled.

Answer (score 1):

after
 
    `systemctl restart php-fpm`
the Gd library works.

Answer (score 1):

I am replying in 2022, anyone still facing this problem may my answer helpful. If your PHP version,n is 8+ you can add the below line to your php.ini file which is located in the PHP folder.

```
extension=php_gd.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

uncomment "extension=gd" in the php ini file

Comment: Tested in PHP 8.2

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this problem by doing the following:

1. Find out which version of php you are running by typing this into the terminal:

`php --version`

My PHP version was 7.4:

```
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Nov  2 2022 09:53:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

2. Install php-7.4-gd

`sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd`

3. Restart Apache

`systemctl restart apache2`