# Fatal error: Call to undefined function: imagejpeg() on Heroku PHP. Fix?

Tags: php, heroku, gd

So, I am getting the following error whilst trying to upload images on my Heroku site (PHP).

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function: imagejpeg()
```

It refers to the following line in my AmazonS3Handler.php file.

```
    //build the jpeg
    imagejpeg($destinationImage);
```

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: Your PHP version doesn't have GD support enabled.

Comment: Oh ok, how can I correct this? It works locally, just not on Heroku

Comment: You need to go to php.ini and check whether your GD library is commented out. If yes, uncomment it.

Answer (score 3):

I had `GD` lib installed and got the same error. The problem was in compiling without `jpeg` support. Here what you should do to make things work.

## 1. Install `libjpeg`

```
apt-get install libjpeg62-turbo-dev
```

## 2. Configure `PHP` with `jpeg` support

```
./configure \
--with-gd
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib64
# other options
```

## 3. Build `PHP`

```
make clean
make
make install
```

Comment: Step 2 should be executed in the `~` folder? Or somewhere else? As well as step 3?

Comment: @DeesOomens step 2 and 3 should be executed in the directory with PHP source code. You can download it from GitHub https://github.com/php/php-src/releases

Comment: For building a docker image (based off php:7.2-apache-stretch), I had to use --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include. The specific commands for the official php image for docker are a bit different (docker-php-ext-configure, docker-php-ext-enable, etc), but it's easy to map the steps above into those.

Answer (score 0):

First stop the local server XAMPP or WAMP

**In XAMPP**

1. Goto xampp installed folder and then go to php folder and find php.ini file
2. and see if your GD library is commented out. If so, remove the comment.
3. ;extension=gd (this one is commented one)
4. extension=gd (Remove ; to uncomment)

Example path: C:\xampp\php\php.in

**In wamp**

1. Go to the wamp installed folder, then to the bin folder, and then go to the php folder.
2. And then goto php7.0.10, php5.6.25, or something else php version folder and find php.ini file.
3. ;extension=gd (this one is commented one)
4. extension=gd (Remove ; to uncomment)

Example path: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10

*If you can't find the extension=gd, add it yourself*

Find "extension=" in the php.ini file and place it after any extension.

**Then restart your local server, and everything should be fine.**