# Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() and GD enabled

Tags: php, ubuntu, opencart, gd

im working on ubuntu 14.04 LTS with PHP 5.5.9 
with GD enabled and i doubled check with 
but still showing me this msg everytime  i try to use imagecreatefromjpeg()

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() in /../library/image.php on line 34

i even tried to check on it from command line by using this

```
php -r "var_dump(function_exists('imageantialias'));"
```

and it gives me back
bool(false)

is there anyway to fix this without re compiling it?

Comment: From the documentation: `JPEG support is only available if PHP was compiled against GD-1.8 or later.`

Comment: looks like this one is a double:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338339/imagecreatefromjpeg-and-similar-functions-are-not-working-in-php

Comment: i've tried every possible solution with that post and it didnt work out

Comment: OK, so why not trying this call: `php -r "var_dump(function_exists('imagecreatefromjpeg'));"`? Or try this `var_dump(function_exists('imagecreatefromjpeg'));` from within the file where this method should be used (and before it is called of course).

Comment: How do you know `gd` is enabled? PHP from web and PHP from CLI might have different configurations.

Comment: "var_dump(function_exists('imagecreatefromjpeg'));" returns true

Comment: i know its enabled cuz
php --ri gd

gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => 2.1.1-dev
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.5.2
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 8
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.50
WBMP Support => enabled
XPM Support => enabled
libXpm Version => 30411
XBM Support => enabled
WebP Support => enabled

Comment: For ubantu 16.* use "sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you've installed an incomplete version of `gd`.
When you compile the `gd` extension, use the flag `--with-jpeg-dir=DIR` and `--with-freetype-dir=DIR`

ps. dont forget `make clean`

picture below is the `incomplete` version of gd:

[image]

picture below is the `complete` version of gd:
[image]

Comment: Make emphasis on "don't forget make clean".

Answer (score 8):

In my case, GD was missing after upgrading to PHP 7.3. So, I just added it by using the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd
```

Answer (score 4):

Find php.ini
generally **C:\xampp\php** (in windows system) then open php.ini

1. find extension=gd
2. Uncomment (remove ; from the start of the line)
3. Stop Xampp and start

Hope will work as here it's working!

[image]

Answer (score -3):

```
Try this
<?php
function LoadJpeg($imgname)
{
    /* Attempt to open */
    $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imgname);

    /* See if it failed */
    if(!$im)
    {
        /* Create a black image */
        $im  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30);
        $bgc = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $tc  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

        imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 150, 30, $bgc);

        /* Output an error message */
        imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, 'Error loading ' . $imgname, $tc);
    }

    return $im;
}

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$img = LoadJpeg('bogus.image');

imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Comment: And this does what? Why should the OP do this? SO requires comments and details NOT just code examples.