# How do I add GD support to php 7.3 from xxamp?

Tags: php, php-gd

I've got stuck with using of GD library.
I have installed and enabled at php.ini (extension=gd2) the library but when I try to use it I'm getting the error: Call to undefined function App\Http\Middleware\imagecreatefromjpeg().

They say that it should be used --with-jpeg-dir flag. How do I add this flag to Configure Command like at the screenshot attached?

[image: --with-jpeg-dir]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [imagecreatefromjpeg and similar functions are not working in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338339/imagecreatefromjpeg-and-similar-functions-are-not-working-in-php)

Comment: Below is the answer:
This was Laravel project and there's an ability to run the site using 'php artisan serve' command which starts its own(in-built) Apache and this Apache doesn't have GD installed. It needs to set up virtual host for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread on a similar topic.

[StackOverflow: imagecreatefromjpeg and similar functions are not working in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338339/imagecreatefromjpeg-and-similar-functions-are-not-working-in-php)

Comment: Thanks Azeame!
The matter is that this is Laravel project. There's an ability to run the site using 'php artisan serve' command which starts its own(in-built) Apache and this Apache doesn't have GD installed. That's why I got the error.
I've set up virtual host for the purpose and now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This was Laravel project and there's an ability to run the site using 'php artisan serve' command which starts its own(in-built) Apache and this Apache doesn't have GD installed.
It needs to set up virtual host for the purpose.