# PHP - Windows imagecreatefromjpg() is undefined

Tags: php, gd2

I have `Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpg()` error. Although i added gd library as `extension=php_gd2.dll` in `php.ini` problem still occurs. What do i need to do?

OS: Windows 10

Edit: Not using XAMPP

Edit2:

`vardump(gd_info())` was showing that everything was correct( also `phpinfo()` says `GD Support: enabled` `GD Version: bundled (2.1.0 compatible)`). I used `imagecreatefromjpeg()` instead and saved as `imagepng($im, '/imagename.jpg');` which led me to have jpg still (code is adding `png` watermark to an image). But still no idea why `imagecreatefromjpg()` didnt work

`gd_info()`:

```
array(14) {
 ["GD Version"]=>
 string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)"
 ["FreeType Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["FreeType Linkage"]=>
 string(13) "with freetype"
 ["GIF Read Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["GIF Create Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["JPEG Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["PNG Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["WBMP Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["XPM Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["XBM Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["WebP Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["BMP Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["TGA Read Support"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=>
 bool(false)
}
```

Comment: Execute `php -m` in command line to ensure if the extension has been installed correctly

Comment: A silly question, but still noteworthy: have you restarted the server after you made the changes?

Comment: Which php.ini did you edit? What does `phpinfo()` show? Have you been through all the suggestions in all the duplicates here? Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338339/imagecreatefromjpeg-and-similar-functions-are-not-working-in-php.

Comment: edited the question. yes i've checked that @Don'tPanic

Answer (score 0):

The function imagecreatefromjpg doesn't exist in PHP. The correct name is:
imagecreatefromjpeg

You can check on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php