# Config\ConfigController->classLoadPage() #8 {main} thrown in

Tags: php

Sirs,

I am getting an error from a function I created. The purpose of the function is to save an image. I have copied my source and error below.

I'm not sure what it could be, did I do something wrong?

```
private function validadeFormatImage() {
    switch ($this->dadosImg['type']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->dadosImg['tmp_name']);
            $this->resizeImg();
            $this->validateDirectory();
            imagejpeg($this->imgResized, $this->directory . $this->nameImg);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
        case 'image/x-png':
            $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($this->dadosImg['tmp_name']);
            $this->resizeImg();
            $this->validateDirectory();
            imagepng($this->imgResized, $this->directory . $this->nameImg);
            break;
    }
}
```

```
Source line 49: $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->dadosImg['tmp_name']);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> Module\administrative\Models\helper\imagecreatefromjpeg() in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\DevHomologacao\adm\module\administrative\Models\helper\AdmsUploadImgRed.php:49
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\DevHomologacao\adm\module\administrative\Models\helper\AdmsUploadImgRed.php(33):
> Module\administrative\Models\helper\AdmsUploadImgRed->validadeFormatImage()
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\DevHomologacao\adm\module\site\Models\StsEditSobCompany.php(70):
> Module\administrative\Models\helper\AdmsUploadImgRed->uploadImd(Array,
> '../site/assets/...', 'perfil2.jpg', 500, 400) #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\DevHomologacao\adm\module\site\Models\StsEditSobCompany.php(51):
> Module\site\Models\StsEditSobCompany->uploadNewImage() #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\DevHomologacao\adm\module\site\Controllers\EditSobCompany.php(39):
> Module\site\Models\StsEditSobCompany->alterSobCompany(Array) #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\DevHomologacao\adm\module\site\Controllers\EditSobCompany.php(25):
> Module\site\Controllers\EditSobCompany->editSobCompany() #5
> C:\xampp\htdocs\DevHomologacao\adm\config\ConfigController.php(101):
> Module\site\Controllers\EditSobCompany->editInfoSobCompany('1') #6
> C:\xampp\htdocs\DevHomologacao\adm\config\ConfigController.php(83):
> Config\ConfigController->checkMethod() #7
> C:\xampp\htdocs\DevHomologacao\adm\index.php(10):
> Config\ConfigController->classLoadPage() #8 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\DevHomologacao\adm\module\administrative\Models\helper\AdmsUploadImgRed.php
> on line 49

Comment: Based on the error message, do you have the function that is coming up as undefined? Can you post the code for `imagecreatefromjpeg()`. I think that would be best place to start.

Comment: You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338339/imagecreatefromjpeg-and-similar-functions-are-not-working-in-php

Answer (score 1):

```
private function validadeFormatImage()
{
    switch ($this->dadosImg['type']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            $this->image = $this->imagecreatefromjpeg($this->dadosImg['tmp_name']);
            $this->resizeImg();
            $this->validateDirectory();
            imagejpeg($this->imgResized, $this->directory . $this->nameImg);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
        case 'image/x-png':
            $this->image = $this->imagecreatefrompng($this->dadosImg['tmp_name']);
            $this->resizeImg();
            $this->validateDirectory();
            imagepng($this->imgResized, $this->directory . $this->nameImg);
            break;
    }
}
```

- if you want to call same class function in side of function use `$this->`

Comment: When trying to use $this-> I get
'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Module\administrative\Models\helper\AdmsUploadImgRed::imagecreatefromjpeg() in'

Comment: @Pedro in same class this function exiting or not?

Comment: The problem was because the GD was disabled, enabling it in php.ini, it worked perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338339/imagecreatefromjpeg-and-similar-functions-are-not-working-in-php
Thank you very much.